# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken with MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongomapper

I'm using Rails 2.3.8 with Ruby 1.8.7 (both installed via CPanel) and gem 1.3.7 and I'm using MongoDB.

Well, I get the following error when I'm trying to create an user (class User):

```
Processing UsersController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-11-13 16:09:55) [POST]
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create", authenticity_token"=>"3AdGHqazhzJUddjLDIKSNzcGTR8KN1Hh7PL+9+vrJ74=", "user"=> "name"=>"jqa"}}

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken)


Rendering /home/jqa/public_html/web/public/422.html (422 Unprocessable Entity)
```

Any Help? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you using rails form helper to generate the registration form? I guess not and thats why you are getting this error. I suggest you to use form_for or form_tag method for the form.

You are getting this because rails generate an authenticity token along with the generated form which gets posted back on form submit as a hidden field. With this rails can assume that it is an authentic request from the same app.

If you have generated the form with hand crafter html, this hidden field wont be there in the form and that why rails is cribbing about it!

Comment: Thank you Selva, but I'm using form_for to generate the creation form. In fact, you can see AuthenticyToken is one of the parameters which is passed in the form, by POST.

Comment: Are you getting this error always or only during on certain occasions?

Comment: I don't know. In fact, this is my first class in RoR + MongoDB